# How to disable some options in an <optgroup> in Select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 4.0.3. I want to disable some options in them.

I have this:

```
<select id="id" class="js-example-basic-multiple select2-offscreen" multiple="multiple" style="width: 100%" tabindex="-1">
    <optgroup label="Preferred">
        <option value="12">Will</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Not preferred">
        <option disabled="disabled" value="1">Will</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="2">Jerry</option>
        <option disabled="disabled" value="3">Anzee</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>

$('#id').select2({
   placeholder: 'Select',
   disabled: true
});
```

Comment: Did you check https://select2.github.io/examples.html#disabled

Comment: Yes it disables the whole select box , i want to disable some options in it

Comment: @Mehdi so you want to hide only particular options in select2 right.?

Comment: yes absolutely right